# onComplete is not getting called when returning response as Flowable

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to make webservie call using retrofit and rxjava 2. i was exploring two different approach to use RxJava2. problem is i am getting response whene i use `Observable` but it is not working with `Flowable`. Logs are not getting printed when using `Flowable` i tried to debug it but its not going inside `onNext` or `onComplete` or `onError`. only `onSubscribe` gets executed.

1) using observable as return type

```
new WebRequestManager().getContactObservable(userRequest)   
    .subscribe(new Observer<ResponseData>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onNext(ResponseData responseData) {

                       Log.e(TAG , "data "+responseData.getStatus());
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onComplete() {

                       Log.e(TAG , "data complete");

                   }
               }
    );
```

2) Using flowable as return type

```
new WebRequestManager().getContactFlowable(userRequest)

 .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseData>() {
     @Override
     public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {

         Log.e(TAG , "contact subscription ");

     }

     @Override
     public void onNext(ResponseData responses) {

         Log.e(TAG , "contact onNext ");


     }

     @Override
     public void onError(Throwable t) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onComplete() {

         Log.e(TAG , "contact onComplete ");
     }
 });
```

Rest contact retrofit api

```
public interface ContactApi {

    @POST(WebRequest.GET_CONTACTS)
    Flowable<ResponseData> getContactFlowable(@Body UserRequest userRequest);

    @POST(WebRequest.GET_CONTACTS)
    Observable<ResponseData> getContactObservable(@Body UserRequest userRequest);

}
```

call to webservice

```
public Flowable<ResponseData> getContactsData(UserRequest userRequest){
        return webRequest.getWebClient().create(ContactApi.class).getContacts(userRequest);


    }

    public Observable<ResponseData> getContact(UserRequest userRequest){
        return webRequest.getWebClient().create(ContactApi.class).getContact(userRequest);

    }
```

getting retrofit instance

```
 public static Retrofit getWebClient(){

        //if(okHttpClient == null)
            okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .connectTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .readTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .writeTimeout(120,TimeUnit.SECONDS)

                                    .addInterceptor(new WebRequestInterceptor("\"application/json\""))
                                    .build();


      // if(client == null)
        client = new  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(LoganSquareConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return client;
    }
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.2-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html#onSubscribe-org.reactivestreams.Subscription-) and [§2.1](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#2.1).

Comment: can you please provide some relevant example where in its been explain how to use flowable with publisher ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Subscriber`s, you have to call `request` to get items:

```java
new WebRequestManager().getContactFlowable(userRequest)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
            Log.e(TAG , "contact subscription ");
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE); // <---------------------------------
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ResponseData responses) {
            Log.e(TAG , "contact onNext ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.e(TAG , "contact onComplete ");
        }
   });
```

See also [DisposableSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subscribers/DisposableSubscriber.html) with its example.

Comment: That worked !!! you are an expert of RxJava saw your profile,  can you please help me how to sharpen the skills of RxJava..roadmap or something

Comment: Read [Learning RxJava](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-rxjava).